# Чем можно заменить JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Прочитал о изменениях в java и немного испугался.
Одно из нововведений будет удаление JavaFX, как я понял удаление полное.
Для меня просто JavaFX самый быстрый и удобный способ построения интерфейса.
В встроенной библиотеке есть ещё Swing и AWT, но на мой взгляд они не так хороши как JavaFX.
Есть ли какие-то аналоги JavaFX, схожие по простоте и конечному результату?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev) уже [отвечал](https://toster.ru/q/538922):

> Его не удалят, а вынесут из стандартной библиотеки в отдельный модуль. Вы сможете и дальше его использовать.
>
> P.S. Вполне возможно, что со временем в отдельный модуль вынесут и Swing.

Так что успокойтесь, ничего не удалят. ИМХО, JavaFX не так часто используется, все таки Java - язык для интерпрайза(считайте, для работы на серверах), где GUI не особо и нужен.

Comment: Т.е. он будет не встроен, а просто как отдельная библиотека скачиваться и подключаться?

Comment: @Andrew скорее всего. Как log4j, JUnit, и т.п.

Comment: @Andrew он всё ещё остаётся в составе JRE, только оформляется отдельным модулем.

Comment: @AntonSorokin согласно [этой странице](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html), Java FX переехала в OpenJDK, так что, видимо, развитием Java FX станет OpenJFX

Comment: OpenJFX выйдет примерно одновременно с выходом 11 jdk, подключить его можно уже сейчас для тестов обычной зависимостью.